# Doctrine ORM query builder fetch key value pair

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have the following code in an entity repository:

```php
$rows = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->select(['t.idColumn', 't.valueColumn'])
    ->where('t.foo = :foo')
    ->orderBy('t.idColumn', 'ASC')
    ->setParameter('foo', $foo)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getArrayResult(); // This returns [[idColumn => ..., valueColumn => ...], ...]
$data = [];

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $data[$row['idColumn']] = abs($row['valueColumn']); // Remapping to [id => value]
}

return $data;
```

Is there any way to get rid of the custom remapping natively? I know that you can use the indexBy parameter, but that only gets me the correct keys but not values.

P.S. I know of array_column(), but that's an extra step that I have to make every time, not to mention it doesn't work on methods that entities have.

P.P.S. This is not using Symfony.

Answer (score 2):

It does not appear this is a feature implemented in the QueryBuilder, however fetchAllKeyValue was added in DBAL 2.11 to the `Connection` object.

[Commit](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/4338), [usage](https://github.com/morozov/dbal/blob/f1a901efbbac5ac6a4749e1fe85634cfe68deb48/docs/en/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.rst#fetchallkeyvalue)

Comment: Yeah, I found that, but no matching stuff on ORM side, and from what I understand it doesn't really work with ORM, needs native support. Also, I'm not using Symfony, and the whole point of this is to avoid writing plain SQL.

Comment: Sorry, I've been using Symfony so much lately I forgot people use Doctrine by itself. I'll edit out that part of the answer. I was able to test it and confirm it works, but looks like you're only option is to submit an issue/PR on github.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use your own function that creates an iterator

```php
function &keyedBy(array &$a, string $key, ?string $value): Iterator {
    foreach ($a as &$v) {
        yield $v[$key] => $value ? $v[$value] : $v;
    }
}

$rows = keyedBy($rows, 'idColumn', 'idKey');
```

An iterator can then be used like an array in some cases, like in a `foreach` but not for direct key access like a hash map (you can use `iterator_to_array` to convert to a real array in that case)

It has the advantage of not looping beforehand and only keying on demand

Comment: The fact is that PDO supports querying a key-value map (https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_KEY_PAIR), and Doctrine is based on PDO, yet does not implement this. There should be no need for a workaround like this.

Comment: You can always open a PR there, it's likely it will be accepted. Right now this iterator is the implementation that made it into doctrine